# Why doesn't Cherrypy example application run on Chrome, but on other browsers

Tags: python, google-chrome, localhost, cherrypy

I didn't get Cherrypy to work with Chrome so far, but I would like to.
So here is the code:

```
import cherrypy 
class HelloWorld(object):
    def index(self):
        return "Hello World!"
    index.exposed = True

cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld())
```

when I run this on my Mac OS X 10.7.3 with Python 2.6 and I enter:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

it works for: Firefox, Opera, Safari

Chrome: doesn't work => "Oops, couldn't connect ... "

Can anyone reproduce this? Where is my mistake here?

Edit: Here is the output from the start

```
[15/Apr/2012:14:09:17] ENGINE Listening for SIGHUP.
[15/Apr/2012:14:09:17] ENGINE Listening for SIGTERM.
[15/Apr/2012:14:09:17] ENGINE Listening for SIGUSR1.
[15/Apr/2012:14:09:17] ENGINE Bus STARTING
CherryPy Checker:
The Application mounted at '' has an empty config.

[15/Apr/2012:14:09:17] ENGINE Started monitor thread 'Autoreloader'.
[15/Apr/2012:14:09:17] ENGINE Started monitor thread '_TimeoutMonitor'.
[15/Apr/2012:14:09:17] ENGINE Serving on 127.0.0.1:8080
[15/Apr/2012:14:09:17] ENGINE Bus STARTED
```

Comment: There's nothing in your code to suggest an error that would only occur on Chrome.  Are there any error statements in your terminal?

Comment: There are no errors in the terminal, when Chrome tries to load, nothing in the terminal appears

Comment: It might be that CP is binding to a different address. Perhaps you could paste the "Serving HTTP on ____" line from CherryPy's log.

Comment: Its wild attempt but something to do with your connection settings in chrome? eg proxy? Anyways cherrypy doesn't have to do anything to what browser you use..

Comment: added the output after the start, maybe that helps?! I don't use a proxy, so no special settings in chrome.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the host to 0.0.0.0. e.g.
cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_host':'0.0.0.0', 'server.socket_port':8000})